Why does linux use different GDT for each CPU?
I don’t understand the reason behind using different GDT for each CPU in multiprocessor systems (in linux).
The TSS descriptor needs to be unique for each CPU, but we could create a descriptor per CPU in a “main” GDT.
Is the GDT get modified after it is initialized?
Are there some other descriptors that can’t be shared by different CPUs?
Is there any other reason I'm missing?
Couldn’t find any relevant information regarding this online,
thanks!

Are you talking about a 32-bit or a 64-bit kernel?  I vaguely recall that for 32 bits, the kernel would set up a segment per CPU pointing to the CPU-local data area, and store its selector in one of the extra segment registers, so that it could access a CPU-local variable with mov eax, [fs:0x123] or the like.  If you have just one GDT, then those segments all have different selectors, and each CPU has to know which one to use.

With one GDT per CPU, they can all have the same selector, so that something like mov ax, 0x20 ; mov fs, ax ; mov eax, [fs:0x123] accesses the correct CPU-local object no matter which CPU executes it.  But in 64-bit mode, segmentation doesn't really exist, and we have FSBASE/GSBASE for this purpose.

Of course the ultimate "relevant information" is the kernel source code...
